# PROBLEMS WITH SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE Kudler_FF
INSERT INTO Job_Tbl
    (JobTitle, JobDescription, ExemptionStatus)
VALUES
   ('Accounting clerk’, ‘Computes, classifies, records, and verifies numerical
   data for use in maintaining accounting records’, ‘N);
```

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string 'Accounting clerk’, ‘Computes, classifies, records,
>   and verifies numerical    data for use in maintaining accounting
>   records’, ‘N); '. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax
>   near 'Accounting clerk’, ‘Computes, classifies, records, and verifies
>   numerical    data for use in maintaining accounting records’, ‘N'.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the closing quote (') after the 'N in your last value...  It should read:

USE Kudler_FF INSERT INTO Job_Tbl (JobTitle, JobDescription, ExemptionStatus) VALUES ('Accounting clerk', 'Computes, classifies, records, and verifies numerical data for use in maintaining accounting records', 'N');

Also as noted above, make sure you're using a forward apostrophe only (', under the " key) and not the open and closing quotes.  The error message you pasted though is about the missing quote after the N, so I think StackOverflow might have put those in via its editor.

Answer (score 2):

You have left and right ticks here:

```
clerk’, ‘Computes,
```

And in a bunch of other spots in your code.

SQL no likey.  Try replacing with a regular apostrophe (`'` not `’` or `‘`)

This will sometimes happen if you copy and past from Word or something like that that tries to do fancy formatting.

Comment: No problem! If you feel like my answer solved your problem feel free to accept it by clicking on the check mark image in the top left corner of my answer.